# How to change the new workspace icon to the older icon?

Tags: unity, launcher, themes, icons

The new "Workspace" icon is very similar the "Terminal" icon and I prefer the older icon. How can I change it?

[image: New]

[image: older]

P.S.: Sorry for my English ;-)

Answer (score 7):

In a `gnome-terminal` do:

- Backup the old icon:

  ```
  sudo mv /usr/share/icons/unity-icon-theme/apps/48/workspace-switcher.png{,.bak}
  ```
- Convert the old icon from SVG to PNG and place it in the correct directory (this needs the `convert` program from the `imagemagick` package, which is not installed by default):

  ```
  sudo convert -background None /usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/48/gnome-panel-workspace-switcher.svg /usr/share/icons/unity-icon-theme/apps/48/workspace-switcher.png
  ```
- Update the theme's icon cache:

  ```
  sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/unity-icon-theme
  ```
- Restart unity

  ```
  (unity &)
  ```

The downside: whenever the icon theme gets updated, you'd need to repeat that process.

Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: What application or package do I need for convert? It's not installed.

Comment: Oh sorry, the `convert` program is part of the `imagemagick` package.

Comment: @Novatillasku Don't forget to mark my answer as *accepted* by clicking on the checkbox next to it (only if you think it answered your question, of course ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

If you change your icon theme, it usually changes that icon as well. Personally I use an older version of the humanity theme along with the one in 11.04. To achieve the same thing, you can copy the theme from an older install (or a Live CD for example).

If you need it, I can link to the older theme (optionally), or even tell you to make a custom theme that will keep all of the new icons (and remain updated) while using the old icon (leave me a comment and I will update my answer).

Comment: I have older iso and can look it.Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way that doesn't involve converting and things like that. 
you can simply set a customized icon in `/usr/share/applications`.
I explained it [in my blog](http://blog.shevin.info/2012/09/how-to-add-custom-icon-for-specific.html) in detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, you should post a sufficient summary here instead of relying on a link.